# How to write bulkUpdate with condition statement in Sequelize nodejs. Update a list of elements with some condition for every element

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, bulkupdate

I am trying to write a query like this

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name1 = CASE WHEN column_name2="asd" THEN comun_name1="123" 
WHEN column_name2="qwe" THEN comun_name1="456"
WHEN column_name2="ghj" THEN comun_name1="568" END
```

with sequelize bulkUpdate, but i can not find an example or any references in documentation.